# Solving for Coefficients of Multivariable Polynomial from Expanded Form

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have 3 single variable polynomials in x, y, and z that have been multiplied together (expanded).  I have the numerical coefficients of the expanded polynomial and want to solve for the a, b, and c coefficients in the simplified polynomials.  My attempts to the solve this have yielded nothing because how over constrained this problem is.  Basically there are 10 unknowns in 64 equations because two of the three leading coefficient (a3,b3,c3) values should be chosen.  Suggestions on how to solve?

Solve for a3, a2, a1, a0, b3, b2, b1, b0, c3, c2, c1, and c0 coefficients. Suggestions?
$$ 
\left( a3\,{x}^{3}+a2\,{x}^{2}+a1\,x+a0\right) \,\left( b3\,{y}^{3}+b2\,{y}^{2}+b1\,y+b0\right) \,\left( c3\,{z}^{3}+c2\,{z}^{2}+c1\,z+c0\right) = u01\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{3}+u02\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{3}+u05\,x\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{3}+u20\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{3}+u03\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{3}+u06\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{3}+u11\,x\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{3}+u31\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{3}+u08\,{x}^{3}\,y\,{z}^{3}+u13\,{x}^{2}\,y\,{z}^{3}+u21\,x\,y\,{z}^{3}+u42\,y\,{z}^{3}+u19\,{x}^{3}\,{z}^{3}+u27\,{x}^{2}\,{z}^{3}+u36\,x\,{z}^{3}+u54\,{z}^{3}+u04\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{2}+u07\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{2}+u12\,x\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{2}+u32\,{y}^{3}\,{z}^{2}+u09\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{2}+u14\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{2}+u22\,x\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{2}+u43\,{y}^{2}\,{z}^{2}+u16\,{x}^{3}\,y\,{z}^{2}+u24\,{x}^{2}\,y\,{z}^{2}+u33\,x\,y\,{z}^{2}+u51\,y\,{z}^{2}+u30\,{x}^{3}\,{z}^{2}+u39\,{x}^{2}\,{z}^{2}+u47\,x\,{z}^{2}+u60\,{z}^{2}+u10\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{3}\,z+u15\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{3}\,z+u23\,x\,{y}^{3}\,z+u44\,{y}^{3}\,z+u17\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{2}\,z+u25\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{2}\,z+u34\,x\,{y}^{2}\,z+u52\,{y}^{2}\,z+u28\,{x}^{3}\,y\,z+u37\,{x}^{2}\,y\,z+u45\,x\,y\,z+u58\,y\,z+u41\,{x}^{3}\,z+u49\,{x}^{2}\,z+u56\,x\,z+u63\,z+u18\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{3}+u26\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{3}+u35\,x\,{y}^{3}+u53\,{y}^{3}+u29\,{x}^{3}\,{y}^{2}+u38\,{x}^{2}\,{y}^{2}+u46\,x\,{y}^{2}+u59\,{y}^{2}+u40\,{x}^{3}\,y+u48\,{x}^{2}\,y+u55\,x\,y+u62\,y+u50\,{x}^{3}+u57\,{x}^{2}+u61\,x+u64  
$$
Equate coefficients
$$u01=a3\,b3\,c3$$
$$u02=a2\,b3\,c3$$
$$u03=a3\,b2\,c3$$
$$u04=a3\,b3\,c2$$
$$u05=a1\,b3\,c3$$
$$u06=a2\,b2\,c3$$
$$u07=a2\,b3\,c2$$
$$u08=a3\,b1\,c3$$
$$u09=a3\,b2\,c2$$
$$u10=a3\,b3\,c1$$
$$u11=a1\,b2\,c3$$
$$u12=a1\,b3\,c2$$
$$u13=a2\,b1\,c3$$
$$u14=a2\,b2\,c2$$
$$u15=a2\,b3\,c1$$
$$u16=a3\,b1\,c2$$
$$u17=a3\,b2\,c1$$
$$u18=a3\,b3\,c0$$
$$u19=a3\,b0\,c3$$
$$u20=a0\,b3\,c3$$
$$u21=a1\,b1\,c3$$
$$u22=a1\,b2\,c2$$
$$u23=a1\,b3\,c1$$
$$u24=a2\,b1\,c2$$
$$u25=a2\,b2\,c1$$
$$u26=a2\,b3\,c0$$
$$u27=a2\,b0\,c3$$
$$u28=a3\,b1\,c1$$
$$u29=a3\,b2\,c0$$
$$u30=a3\,b0\,c2$$
$$u31=a0\,b2\,c3$$
$$u32=a0\,b3\,c2$$
$$u33=a1\,b1\,c2$$
$$u34=a1\,b2\,c1$$
$$u35=a1\,b3\,c0$$
$$u36=a1\,b0\,c3$$
$$u37=a2\,b1\,c1$$
$$u38=a2\,b2\,c0$$
$$u39=a2\,b0\,c2$$
$$u40=a3\,b1\,c0$$
$$u41=a3\,b0\,c1$$
$$u42=a0\,b1\,c3$$
$$u43=a0\,b2\,c2$$
$$u44=a0\,b3\,c1$$
$$u45=a1\,b1\,c1$$
$$u46=a1\,b2\,c0$$
$$u47=a1\,b0\,c2$$
$$u48=a2\,b1\,c0$$
$$u49=a2\,b0\,c1$$
$$u50=a3\,b0\,c0$$
$$u51=a0\,b1\,c2$$
$$u52=a0\,b2\,c1$$
$$u53=a0\,b3\,c0$$
$$u54=a0\,b0\,c3$$
$$u55=a1\,b1\,c0$$
$$u56=a1\,b0\,c1$$
$$u57=a2\,b0\,c0$$
$$u58=a0\,b1\,c1$$
$$u59=a0\,b2\,c0$$
$$u60=a0\,b0\,c2$$
$$u61=a1\,b0\,c0$$
$$u62=a0\,b1\,c0$$
$$u63=a0\,b0\,c1$$
$$u64=a0\,b0\,c0$$

Comment: I think I have the answer/procedure.  I will post it later.